# Animating Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

I Like using Jquery and its companion Jquery Ui but can not find a way to animate background image over a certain period of time like 5 seconds.
I can not do something like:

```
$('sampleelement').animate({'background-image':'url(hello.jpg)'},5000);
```

Any ideas??

Comment: WHat excactly are you trying to achieve? I assumed you were trying to make the background image apear?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible like this. Css does not allow for backgound image manipulation like this. You should put in a div with the background behind your content and fade that in:

```
<div id='background_img' style='display:none; position:absolute;'><!-- position me behind the content!--><img ... /></div> 
<div id='content'>YDADA</div>

$('#background_img').fadeIn(5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [Background-Position Animations](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect) plugin. See the [demo](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an animated GIF?

Comment: Have not experience in creating gif

Answer (score 0):

Pim Jager's approach is about the closest you will get without an animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple images and just replace one with another using setTimeout. It's kind of like emulating .gif, just gives more flexibility and quality.

Answer (score 0):

What I did on [Cheer Us Up](http://cheerusup.com/) is used basic javascript to change the background image --

```
$(function(){
curr = 0;
setTimout(changeBg(),200); 

});

function changeBg() {
curr++;

document.body.style.backgroundPosition = curr + 20;

}
```

That is the basic idea. I didn't use jquery because I just wanted it to slowly slide by.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: http://www.ovalpixels.com/bgImageTransition/